# Internet Explorer, large tables, display:none, CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a really big performance issue with Internet Explorer (8 and 9) and large data tables.

When I loaded a few hundred items, the browser (not only Internet Explorer, but also Chrome and Firefox) starts lagging a lot. At first I thought it was because of JavaScript, but later I realized that it was CSS's fault. I found out that with `display:none` the browser does not render elements, so I made tweaks and started grouping elements in  elements and hiding them when they are not visible in viewport like this:

```
<tbody style="display:none"></tbody>
<tbody></tbody>
```

Performance did really improve in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer seems to still be rendering or trying to recalculate styles for those hidden elements. It looks like `display:none` makes no difference on Internet Explorer. If I could make not rendering work I believe performance should improve, but I don't know how...

Also the reason why browsers starts lagging with large data table is because each row has about 50 elements inside which are also heavily styled with CSS.

I don't know what else to try to fix this in Internet Explorer...

Any ideas?

P.S.: table-layout is set to fixed

Comment: The answer to this question might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787480/gwt-big-tables-load-slow-on-ie7-8

Comment: "every time you insert a table row, IE tries to reflow the entire table so the longer the table, the longer the reflow takes."...

This might be the reason, I need to do more testing tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering speed also depends on the way you create elements to the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), even though the script itself would be executed fast.

By my (Internet Explorer) experience `document.write()` is the fastest way to create large tables. It can be over 100 times faster than `appendChild(document.createElement())`. Also `insertRow() & insertCell()` are remarkable faster than creating and appending each row and cell. `innerHTML` seems to be the slowest method to add content (though in this case it can be used to create cell content only, not the table itself).

Unfortunately these differences between performance are not necessarily cross-browser, one browser is doing the same job faster with some other method than another browser...

What can you do then? Try to "split" your table into several smaller tables. You said that `table-layout: fixed` is set; do you also use `COL` and/or `COLGROUP` tags and `width`s for those? Without them setting `table-layout` is pretty much useless. Or you could use lazy loading; just load a small part of the table, and when needed, load more.

"Example": I've created an Internet Explorer application, which currently shows 379 tables having six rows with eight cells each. To create and render those tables takes less than 2 seconds (in [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9)). However, (I just tested) if I'll create all 2274 rows to a single table, rendering will take about 15 seconds. I assume that splitting the large table to smaller parts would speed up rendering in other browsers too.

Comment: Well the problem is not rendering, problem is after everything is rendered. For some reason whole page starts lagging when I have heavy data table with lots of elements inside.. Simply :hover effects start to lag a lot and any other job that needs repainting

Comment: @VytautasButkus I see, maybe the partial load is your solution. Just keep only the visble part of table in the DOM, (with a bit of marginal ofcourse). Maybe you also need to consider to reduce styling.

Comment: I think I just solved the issue, instead of hiding with display:none I detached elements as you told me. And when I scroll back I insert them back to DOM.

What a great Friday's working day end!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the example code, but you could remove the hidden elements from the DOM.

So instead of just setting `display:none`, detach them with `removeChild()` and store them in some object until you need to show them and then insert them at the appropriate place.

Comment: Ok, I might try this. But as I read somewhere display:none means that element is not rendered into DOM. Isn't not rendering and removing from DOM the same?
It seems to work just fine in Chrome and FF, but as I said before looks like IE happens to interpret "not rendering" differently

Comment: P.S. Also I would love to keep those elements in DOM because when scrolling up or down I show/hide them. That way I could save some resources for not re-rendering everything everytime

Answer (score 0):

It is actually an issue for all the Internet Explorer browsers without Internet Explorer 11. In general (for all other browsers) 'display:none' means that everything in it shouldn't be really processed from the browser on load, but Internet Explorer does that for some reason.

The only solution is to keep it out of the DOM and render part of the table.

I had the same problem. I initially had one table with 1000 records which was crashing most browsers (Firefox was the only one processing it). And even if it processed the initial DOM, the table was giving that slow dragging sensation (really annoying). So it was kind of unusable.

Then I divided it into smaller tables (200 records) with select drop-down and display:none from the start. This actually completely fixed the issue with the slow page dragging for all browsers. The only problem remained the slow (it takes about 2000 ms) initial load in Internet Explorer 10, 9, 8.

The only way to fix that unfortunately is to specifically exclude the tables from the DOM before load.

Answer (score 0):

Having used `display:none` on elements that aren't being viewed myself, I can assure you that it is a massive performance gain, even in IE.

The problem you have here is that the browser is constantly having to recalculate column sizes, especiallywhen you change `display` properties.

To fix, try adding `table-layout:fixed` to your table's styles. This will effectively disable dynamic column widths and make for more consistent viewing when elements change. You may need to specify `width`s for your first row, however. This should result in an astronomical performance gain in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the redrawing issue, use a document fragment. Children appended to the document fragment are not rendered and will not cause the issues you see. You can then insert the fragment itself into the table:

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// The following is pseudo code, but you get the picture
for (var i = 0; i < largeCount; i++) {
    var row = createRow();
    docFrag.appendChild(row);
}

// Append the fragment to the table (or even tbody)
var tbl = document.getElementById('myTbl');
tbl.appendChild(docFrag);
```

The document fragment itself does not render as anything, it is basically a container element that acts as a placeholder and disappears after you insert it into something.

EDIT: Further information can be found [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DocumentFragment).